# UINavigationController: Keep subview visible and let pushed ViewController be blurred

Tags: ios

I have a UINavigationController and if I debug(Debug View Hierarchy) I can see that the UINavigationController is not keeping the beneath UIViewControllers views visible.

I need the view to be blurred, and I know how to make a view blurred - but obviously it does not work if UINavigationController is hiding the view beneath.

Do you know how to do this - hope I explain myself.